# DPM 2012 running powershell script in task scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-task, scdpm

I'm having a problem running a custom PS script I created to attach systems into the console.

My PS script works when i'm running it interactively in the DPM Management Shell.

I was referencing this site: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dpmpowershell/thread/ef802ac3-b5c8-4b8d-a29b-8d4a24bd3eca/

I have been testing the script in cmd.

```
Connect-DPMServer : Unable to connect to contoso-dpm01.fake.com. (ID:948)
Verify that the DPM service is running on this computer.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\DPM\DPM\bin\Attach-ProductionS
erver.ps1:49 char:31
```

The script is a a simple one that passes computer names to the Attach-ProductionServer.ps1

Thanks for reading.
-Paul

Here's my script:

```
param([string] $DPMServerName, [string] $PSFileList)

 if(!$args[0])
{
   if(!$DPMServerName)
   {
       $DPMServerName = "contoso-dpm01.fake.com"
   }
}

   if(!$PSFileList)
   {
       $PSFileList = "\\Share1\DPM_LOGS.txt"
   }

$UserName =  "`$DomAdmin"
$pwd = "Password"
$Domain = "fake.com"
$installPath = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Data Protection Manager\Setup" "UIInstallPath").UIInstallPath
$dpmModuleFullPath = $installPath + "Modules\DataProtectionManager\DataProtectionManager.psd1"
Import-Module $dpmModuleFullPath


type $PSFileList | foreach -process {
    if (!$_.Equals(""))
    {
        .\Attach-ProductionServer.ps1 -DPMServerName $DPMServerName -PSName $_  -Username $UserName -    Password $pwd -domain $Domain
       }
}
# Get the date
$DateStamp = get-date -uformat "%m-%d-%y@%H-%M"
rename-item $PSFileList $DateStamp
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a DPMServer called `contoso.com`? Using a sample script? Or did you deliberately set in that name for the sake of obscurity?

Comment: I set that in the name :D Management would be unhappy if my FQDN was published

Comment: But, is it the FQDN of the DPM Server? Or the name of a client/agent computer? Could you post your script?

Comment: The script will read a txt file that is populated with the computer names.  It will pass each computer name through the loop and attach all systems to DPM.  I have confirmed that this works when i run it from DPM-Management Shell

Comment: So, the script works when you run it interactively.  How are you running it when it fails? Via scheduled task? What security context is it running under?

Comment: In my experience, this is a UAC issue. The script needs elevation to complete successfully.